# PetaPoco queries in a ViewModel

Tags: petapoco

If I had a viewmodel that looked something like this

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
   public int AddressID {get;set;}
   public string Street {get;set;}
   public string Town {get;set;}
   public SelectList Countries { get; set; }

}
```

How would I go about populating this?

Would it be 2 queries to the database, 1 to populate the address info and another to return all countries into the SelectList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so yes, maybe even cache it if the list values don't change.

Comment: Cache it in Global.asax as a static list you mean?

Comment: I'm quite certain he does not mean caching a static object in Global.asax.  There are many other (better) ways and places to cache objects..

Comment: `Application.Cache` object anyone?

Comment: Actually for a list like countries I would argue statics are the **optimal** location to cache them. As long as you don't plan to add new countries or states while you're site is hot and expect it to update before a recycle.